Metrisability of Adele ring
Let $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ denote the topological ring of adeles over the field of rational numbers. Is its topology metrisable? If so, is it complete, separable under that metric?
I believe that it might be metrisable but I am not able to come up with a metric. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A quick Google search on the phrase "are adeles metrizable" leads to slides here of a talk about work by Sergii Torba and W. A. Zúñiga-Galindo where a metric is shown on slide 19/30 with heading "Metric structure on adeles".
In practice it is much more important to be able to work with the topology on $\mathbb A_\mathbf Q$ directly rather than trying to rely on a metric inducing the adelic topology.
